# How can I switch scim’s IMEs via command line?

Tags: input-method, scim

I have a bunch of SCIM IMEs installed. I switch between them via hot-key.

Is there a way to switch between them programmatically? Can I even switch SCIM on and off via command line? I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to do that at the moment...

Comment: I use the Dvorak keyboard layout normally. I noticed that this remaps the keys of some SCIM methods. So I want to assign a keybinding to change my keyboard back to Qwerty and then select a certain SCIM input method. Seems like a simple task, but I cannot figure out how to do it as there appears to be no documented way to change the SCIM input method programmatically. Have you had any luck with this question since you asked it? I would be happy to use another input method if it provides a command-line interface.

Comment: I don’t use IME these days, but there are new IME, which almost replaced SCIM, as far as I remember... Unfortunately, they lacked in this regard as well: it seemed to be impossible to configure 4 hotkeys to lead to 4 specific variants of 2 or 3 layouts. You always had to cycle through, activate or shift them into some mode. Totally useless. – Keep me posted if you find something!

Comment: If you use fcitx, then there is a [post on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/935165/how-can-i-change-my-fcitx-input-method-from-the-terminal) which tells how to do this. Fcitx is mostly for Chinese, but it seems to support everything else as well. I'm still learning about it...